# Is there a way to click on a button in a window opened using google colab/javascript

Tags: javascript, google-colaboratory

One of my daily work includes going to a webpage, sourcing for the product and clicking "Add to cart".

However, I have a list of products and I am trying out a way to simulate this using google colab.

I understand that I can only use javascript in colab to open the URL in a new tab. However, I do not know how to click on a particular button e.g. "Add to cart" button once I have opened the URL.

Is there a way to do this using google colab/javascript?

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
def automate():
    url = 'https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/SG/en/product/sigald/s9888'
    display(Javascript('window.open("{url}");'.format(url=url)))
    display(Javascript('document.getElementById("P&A-row-quantity-SIGALD-S9888-500G-increment").click();')) 
automate()
```